# Simultaneity Question in Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

The topic of simultaneity is often described with an example using a “stationary” Observer 1 and a traveling vehicle (e.g. train) with an onboard passenger (Observer 2) passing each other at the start.  At that instant they are both centered between two lights that flash at each end of the train.  Then arguments are made regarding the arrival of the flashes at each observer.  The stationary observers is usually said to perceive the flash arrivals simultaneously since equal distances are traveled at the constant speed of light.  Then the movement of the train is said to change the distance each light flashes travels to reach the passenger thus the passenger does not perceive simultaneous arrival.  Some versions of descriptions have the two lights traveling with the train and some do not.  I am finding inconsistences between the descriptions and implications.
Can someone comment on my understanding of the situation and if I am correct or not, since I am not reaching a common conclusion with many of the posted accounts.

My interpretation:
Since the perceived speed of light travel will be the same for all observers in their own reference frames I don’t see that it makes any difference if the lights are attached to the traveling train or attached to the ground when flashed.  At that instant, the light pulses are seen by everyone to start moving toward themselves at constant (relative to themselves) speed C.   Then the issue is whether they arrive together or not, as perceived by each observer.

The “stationary” Observer 1 see simultaneous arrival of the light pulses at his location based on equal speeds and equal distances of travel for each light pulse.   Observer 1 also sees Observer 2 (on the train) to move closer to one flash location and further from the other flash location in his reference frame during the time of propagation so the flashes are not seen to arrive simultaneously at traveling Observer 2 as seen by stationary Observer 1.

The traveling Observer 2 sees the light pulses traveling toward himself at equal speeds of C in his moving frame and covering equal distances in his reference frame (attached to the train), thus perceives simultaneous arrival of the light pulses.  Observer 2 sees Observer 1 (on the ground) to move closer to one light pulse and further from the other during propagation thus sees different arrival times for Observer 1, just the opposite conclusions as made by Observer 1.

My interpretation says that each observer senses simultaneous arrival of light for himself and not for the other observer.  I also say that the same description applies regardless if the lights are attached to the ground or the moving train.  If you see an error in my interpretation, please explain.  Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "At that instant, the light pulses are seen by everyone" - that's where it goes wrong. The pulses are *not* going to be simultaneous for everyone - that's what relativity of simultaneity is all about. And I'm not saying they won't be *perceived* as such, I'm saying that the emission will *actually* not happen at the same time at both light sources for one of the observers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> If you see an error in my interpretation, please explain.

Your interpretation is not self consistent.

Each observer can write the time that they received each pulse of light, according to their own clock, on a piece of paper.

Different perspectives cannot alter what is written on the paper. And if an interpretation leads to a wrong prediction about the written value then that interpretation is wrong.

> The “stationary” Observer 1 see simultaneous arrival of the light pulses at his location based on equal speeds and equal distances of travel for each light pulse. Observer 1 also sees Observer 2 (on the train) to move closer to one flash location and further from the other flash location in his reference frame during the time of propagation so the flashes are not seen to arrive simultaneously at traveling Observer 2 as seen by stationary Observer 1.

So your interpretation predicts that observer 1’s paper has the same number on it and observer 2’s paper has different numbers

> The traveling Observer 2 sees the light pulses traveling toward himself at equal speeds of C in his moving frame and covering equal distances in his reference frame (attached to the train), thus perceives simultaneous arrival of the light pulses. Observer 2 sees Observer 1 (on the ground) to move closer to one light pulse and further from the other during propagation thus sees different arrival times for Observer 1

So your interpretation also requires that observer 1’s paper have different numbers and observer 2’s paper have the same.

Thus your interpretation is not self consistent. No matter how the experiment transpires something is contradicted

> Observer 1 see simultaneous arrival of the light pulses at his location based on equal speeds and equal distances of travel for each light pulse

This is the key issue. Equal distance and equal speed is insufficient to conclude simultaneous arrival. Equal distance and equal speed and also simultaneous start imply simultaneous arrival. By applying this incorrect logic twice you arrived at a self contradiction

Answer (score 0):

You are right in supposing that it doesn't matter whether the lights are attached to the train, but the rest of your logic is wrong. The key point to bear in mind whenever you are thinking about SR is that there is only one reality- if the photons from the two flashes meet at a certain point, then they meet at that point, full-stop. You cannot have the photons meeting at the centre of the carriage in one frame and at the centre of the platform in another!

So, let's look at the thought experiment from the perspective of the traveller. As she passes the person on the platform there are two flashes at either end of the carriage. It doesn't matter whether the flashes were from lights attached to the carriage or not. Let's say they are lightening bolts which leave scorch marks on the carriage and on the platform. If she sees them as simultaneous, then the photons from each flash must arrive at her eye at the same time. If not- if say the photons from one flash arrived at her eye a second after the photons from the other- she would see the two flashes a second apart. So if the photons arrive at the same time, and if the photons have travelled equal distances (ie from either end of the carriage to the centre) then they must have set off at the same time in the frame of the train, ie the flashes must have been simultaneous in the frame of the train.

Now, from the perspective of the person on the platform, if the photons from the two flashes arrive at the traveller at the same time, they must reach the stationary observer at two different times, since there can only be one reality. The photons from the rear of the train must whizz past the stationary observer first in their trip to meet the photons from the front of the train at the traveller's eye. So if the light from the two flashes reaches the stationary observer at different times, and if, from the scorch marks on the platform, the stationary observer knows the light from each flash has travelled the same distance, then the stationary observer concludes that the flashes were not simultaneous in the frame of the platform.

Hopefully you have followed that logic.

Now, this is where most people get confused. You can also imagine a version of the though experiment in which the light reaches the stationary observer at the same time, so that the stationary observer concludes the flashes were simultaneous in the platform frame. Yes indeed, you can- but the key point is *that is an entirely different set-up. Either the flashes are simultaneous in the platform frame, or they are simultaneous in the carriage frame- the two scenarios you describe in your fourth and fifth paragraphs are two completely different set-ups, so there is no contradiction between them*. If the flashes happen simultaneously in the platform frame, then they do not in the train frame. If they happen simultaneously in the train frame, the they do not in the platform frame. You are simply wrong if you try to imagine a situation in which the same pair of flashes happen simultaneously in both frames.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is when you say,

"The traveling Observer 2 sees the light pulses traveling toward himself at equal speeds..."

None of the observers see the light pulses in transit. They only see them when they arrive. That's what "seeing light" means. I think you are mentally picturing this experiment as an omniscient outside observer, instead of putting yourself in the place of Observer 1 or 2.

Let's say the advancing light is green, and the retreating light is red. Because human eyes cannot see two events 180° apart (at least not well), we have to imagine the observer is looking at 90° to both lights (perpendicular to the train rails) with a set of angled mirrors, allowing him to see both horizons at the same time. This is a point that is often glossed over.

Observer 1 will experience a simultaneous flash of green and red in his mirror, while Observer 2 will experience a green flash, then a red flash.  That is the only input each one has with which to make sense of the events.  And neither observer believes he is moving.

The contention of Relativity is that *both observers are correct*, and neither viewpoint is preferred. Indeed, when we observe two astronomical events like supernovae occur in two different parts of the sky, an alien civilization on a planet far away moving at a different speed and direction would see the flashes at a different interval and possibly in a different order. It would be impossible to say what order or time duration "really" separated the events.*  Such relationships are not absolute or unchanging properties of events.

$^*$ Beyond the scope of the question, but by using quantum mechanics (redshift) and a large scale model of the universe, and choosing a preferred reference frame like the CMB, I think in principle one could assign an $(x,y,z,t)$ coordinate to every observed event, anywhere.  But that requires choosing a preferred frame. (Ignore this note if it just adds confusion).